How can I Subdivide a Mesh into Even Square Faces?
Is there a method in Blender to subdivide a mesh into equal squares regardless of its shape, even after all transformations have been applied to the object?
In this example, I have two images: one is a Cube and the other a Cuboid.
This is the default cube, and the subdivisions consist of equally sized square faces:

And here is the cube stretched. When trying to subdivide, Blender creates rectangular faces instead of square faces. While I know I can manually add loop cuts to achieve this, is there a way Blender can automatically calculate and maintain square face subdivisions on a stretched or deformed object?
In the rectangle shape, the front sides highlighted with red borders are rectangular faces, while the sides of the rectangle have square faces.

In this image, where I added a randomly shaped mesh, is there a method in Blender to create perfect square faces through subdivision?


you could use the Quad remesh, it may be ok with organic objects but it will give a trash result on square or manufactured objects

No, you cannot fit perfect square faces on every cuboid. Let's take a simple example: a cuboid with dimensions that are not multiples of the same number. In this case, you cannot perfectly fit square faces within the cuboid without leaving gaps or overhangs. While you could subdivide the cuboid into smaller square faces, the dimensions of the cuboid would still need to be divisible by the same factor to fit perfectly. This means that to fit squares depends on the specific dimensions of the cuboid.

Well in theory, you could subdivide any cuboid shape into 1mm x 1mm faces to achieve perfectly square faces, which is the smallest possible face size for cuboids with three significant figures, like 1.002m x 1.003m x 1.004m. With cuboid dimensions having two significant figures, such as 1.01m x 1.02m x 1.03m, faces with 10mm x 10mm would fit. For dimensions having one significant figure, like 1.1m x 1.2m x 1.3m, 0.1m x 0.1m faces would fit. Thus, the ability to achieve perfect square faces varies based on the dimensions and their precision. I don't think you want that though.

Well said. And like you explain, that's how it works only with cuboids. If there is an object like the kind of chevron shape in the question or any shape with angles which are not 90°, it will never be possible to get only even square faces.

@GordonBrinkmann Yeah. If it doesn't work perfectly for a simple cuboid, it's even less likely to work for objects with other shapes like you mention. I should have included that statement as well :)
